# JavaScript, is it possible to make it redirect when its at 0?(closed)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript and i am wondering how i can implement a redirect function that will redirect the user to the homepage when the countdown is done. It is for a Under construction/launch site and i would really like it to redirect by itself instead of them refreshing it!
My code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var redirect="my website"
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('#countdown').countDown({
                targetDate: {
                    'day':      <?php echo $row['day'] ?>,
                    'month':    <?php echo $row['month'] ?>,
                    'year':     <?php echo $row['year'] ?>,
                    'hour':     <?php echo $row['hour'] ?>,
                    'min':      <?php echo $row['min'] ?>,
                    'sec':      <?php echo $row['sec'] ?>
                }
            });     
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consult the plugin documentation for a "completed" event/callback.

Comment: Looks like you are using a jQuery plugin there – which one is it? Maybe it has some kind of callback function/event that gets triggered when the counter reaches zero – so look at the documentation for it.

Comment: CBroe:
http://wildmine.tk/js/jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js and http://wildmine.tk/js/jquery-1.4.4.js

Comment: Put your redirection code inside [onComplete](http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/example.php?e=on_complete).

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the documentation there's an `onComplete` callback. This should work.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var redirect="my website"
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#countdown').countDown({
            targetDate: {
                'day':      <?php echo $row['day'] ?>,
                'month':    <?php echo $row['month'] ?>,
                'year':     <?php echo $row['year'] ?>,
                'hour':     <?php echo $row['hour'] ?>,
                'min':      <?php echo $row['min'] ?>,
                'sec':      <?php echo $row['sec'] ?>
            },
            onComplete: function(){
                window.location.replace(redirect);
            }
        });     
    });
</script>
```

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/example.php?e=on_complete

Comment: I saw the link and tested it, but didn't work. Was about to fix the small "mistakes" but you did it for me. So thanks! :)